# Check and compare two objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, types, compare

I have a Buildable abstract class from which inherits the classes House and Road.

I'm trying to classify an array of Buildable objects which contains Houses and Roads.

I know that I can check if a object is a Road like this:  `f(myBuildables[i] is Road)` and it works perfectly, but for scalability reasons I want to have an array that contains the classes that inherits from Buildable. I try some stuff but obviously it doesen't work: `class[] inheritTypes = { House, Road }`

I have also tryied with an array of Types `Types[] buildableTypes = { typeOf(Hosue), typeOf(Road) }` but I cant compare the types because of `typeOf(myBuildables[i])` always returns Buildable type.

Comment: try `Buildable[]`?

Comment: How should I use it?

Comment: How many Buildable Inheritors are you going to have to deal with? Just a warning ahaed: You will not get around a type check. At best you can get *somebody elses code* do this work for you.

Comment: There has been a practically indentical question, but for Winforms. The abstract Class was "abstract Question". I can link you to my answer there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59116927/3346583  | The correct answer really depends on what you are going to *do* with those instances, once you know what their type is.

Comment: I advice you to read this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism

Comment: @Christopher actually I have to deal with around 5 Inheritors, but in the future it will be around 20.
Ok, i will look at your answer

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? "Classifying an array" doesn't sound like an end goal.

Comment: Okay. 20 is indeed to much for even the improoved switch. That would require the `Dictionary<type, delegate>`. Of coruse again: It really depends on what you are planning to **do** with those instances, after you have cast them. | Stuff like progressing a tick? That could be done with a function they inherit from Buildable or get from a interface. Draw? Same deal. Without showing us what you plan to do with at least those two, this is all the information I can give you right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The equivalent functionality of a `is` check on instances but for types is `Type.IsAssignableFrom` ([docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isassignablefrom?view=netframework-4.8)).

In your case:

```
if (typeof(House).IsAssignableFrom(obj.GetType()))
{
//obj is a house
}
```

So you can keep the types in an array and then make your decisions dynamically based on the contents of that array.

Comment: Its worth noting that if you're doing this, your design is probably flawed and there might be a better way. Such as creating an abstract method called `DoYThing()` and `House` implements it and `Road` leaves an empty stub (and another method `DoXThing()` that `House` leaves as a stub and `Road` implements). The whole point of interfaces and abstract classes is that you *shouldn't* need to *ever* perform a cast to its specific type.

Answer (score 1):

Given

```
public abstract class Buildable{}

class Road : Buildable{}
class House : Buildable{}
```

You can do the following

```
List<Buildable> buildables = new List<Buildable>();
buildables.Add(new House());
buildables.Add(new Road());
buildables.Add(new House());

foreach(var item in buildables)
{
    if(item is House)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("House");
    }
    if (item is Road)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Road");
    }
}
```

Or in C# 8.0 you can do advanced pattern matching like the following:

```
abstract class Buildable { 
    public bool Damage;
}

class Road : Buildable { }
class House : Buildable { }
```

And pattern match with:

```
List<Buildable> buildables = new List<Buildable>();
buildables.Add(new House());
buildables.Add(new Road());
buildables.Add(new House{  Damage = true });

foreach (var item in buildables)
{
    switch (item)
    {
        case House damageHouse when damageHouse.Damage:
            Console.WriteLine("House Damaged");
            break;
        case House house:
            Console.WriteLine("House");
            break;
        case Road road:
            Console.WriteLine("Road");
            break;
        case Buildable _:
            Console.WriteLine("Default");
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you should use object.GetType ():

```
myBuildables [I] .GetType ();
```

Here is a sample code:

```
 class Program
    {
        abstract class Buildable
        {
            public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
        }

        class Home : Buildable{}

        class Roard: Buildable{}

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Type> listTypes = new List<Type>()
            {
                typeof(Home),
            };

            List<Buildable> listBuildable = new List<Buildable>()
            {
                new Home(){Name = "home 1"},
                new Home(){Name = "home 2"},
                new Home(){Name = "home 3"},
                new Roard(){Name = "road 1"},
                new Roard(){Name = "road 2"},
                new Roard(){Name = "road 3"},
            };
            foreach(var item in listBuildable)
            {
                var itemType = item.GetType();
                Console.WriteLine("Buildable name = " + item.Name);
                Console.Write("item typeof" + itemType.ToString());

                if (listTypes.Find(o => o.Equals(itemType)) != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(" - Type isset in list");
                else
                    Console.WriteLine(" - Unknown type");

                Console.WriteLine();

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Result:

> Buildable name = home 1 
>   item typeofConsoleApp1.Program+Home - Type isset in list
>
> Buildable name = home 2
>   item typeofConsoleApp1.Program+Home - Type isset in list
>
> Buildable name = home 3
>   item typeofConsoleApp1.Program+Home - Type isset in list
>
> Buildable name = road 1
>   item typeofConsoleApp1.Program+Roard - Unknown type
>
> Buildable name = road 2
>   item typeofConsoleApp1.Program+Roard - Unknown type
>
> Buildable name = road 3
>   item typeofConsoleApp1.Program+Roard - Unknown type

Comment: Won't polymorphic code help here instead of doing so much reflection?

Comment: @Mr.Young  What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Reflection is a fallback. A thing you use if nothing else can fit the bill. If you got a reflection based default, you really should be making a proper, non-reflection based approach.

Comment: @Christopher 
I know, but I suggested a solution that was requested: 
**...but for scalability reasons I want to have an array that contains the classes that inherits from Buildable**

Comment: `Roard` with two `r`s?